# Pyserial ValueError: "port" must be None or a string, not <type 'int'>

Tags: python-2.7, pyserial

I wrote a basic program which should open a serial connection to a device on a comport:

```
import serial
device = serial.Serial(port=5, baudrate=115200, bytesize=8, 
    timeout=1,parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)
```

on one pc this code works. 
on the other it produces this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Lab/Desktop/Seebeck measurement software working version 
170718/testtofinddevice.py", line 15, in <module>
device = serial.Serial(port=5, baudrate=115200, bytesize=8, 
timeout=1,parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 31, in 
__init__
super(Serial, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\serial\serialutil.py", line 218, in 
__init__
self.port = port
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\serial\serialutil.py", line 264, in port
raise ValueError('"port" must be None or a string, not 
{}'.format(type(port)))
ValueError: "port" must be None or a string, not <type 'int'>`enter code here`
```

Comment: I believe `port`, which you set to `5`, should be set to a string e.g `"5"`.

Comment: with quotes I get: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\testtofinddevice.py", line 2, in <module>
    device = serial.Serial(port="5", baudrate=115200)
  ...File "C:\...\serialwin32.py", line 62, in open
    raise SerialException("could not open port {!r}: {!r}".format(self.portstr, ctypes.WinError()))
SerialException: could not open port '5': WindowsError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified.')

Comment: are you sure your device name is called "5"? from [pyserial's api](http://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial): "port is a device name: depending on operating system. e.g. `/dev/ttyUSB0` on GNU/Linux or `COM3` on Windows."

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the version of pyserial, not the version of Python.  They changed the parameter from an int to a string between pyserial 2.7 (which can be installed on Python 3.x) and pyserial 3.x.  I now have code like this for most of my programs:

```
if (float(serial.VERSION) >= 3.0):
    portnamenum = sys.argv[1]
    print ("Opening " + portnamenum)
else:
    portnamenum = int(sys.argv[1])
    print ("Opening com" + str(portnamenum))
ser = serial.Serial(port=portnamenum, baudrate=19200, bytesize=8, parity="E", stopbits=1, timeout=0.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found the solution myself. But I don't understand why it is working on two pc in a diffrent way:
on one you need this code in order for it to work:
import serial
device = serial.Serial(port=5, baudrate=115200, bytesize=8, 
    timeout=1,parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)

on the other this code:
import serial
device = serial.Serial(port="COM6", baudrate=115200, bytesize=8, 
    timeout=1,parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)

so there seem to be 2 diffrent versions of the pyserial I guess???

Comment: please see my answer....  it's the version of pyserial that's different between the two machines...  do a "pip freeze" at the command line of each machine, You will likely have one at pyserial 2.x (port=5), and one at pyserial 3.x (port="com6").